# Custom Armor Minecraft Forge 1.8 Armor Model Texture

Tags: java, minecraft

I have been doing some Minecraft Modding with forge and version 1.8. I have gotten to custom armor and it says I need to create a custom armor model texture. There are 2 layers. Layer one consists of helmet chest and boots while layer 2 is the legs. The premade templates make no sense to me. It does not look like helmets, chest or boots at all. Could someone explain to me why they are used and why does it look wierd?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an armour piece it consists out of multiple squares and sometimes triangles. The image is composed so the graphics card can wrap the image over the entire model. The way it does that is complex but it ends up that it needs the images in that order.

That's why it looks so weird. There is a reason Notch had to write a specialised piece of code to be able to make the dragon skin. The wrapping is more complex there.

For some reading enjoyment http://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/Textures.html